# What is difference between User.save().then((doc)=>{..}).catch((err)=>{}) And save((err,doc)=>{...})

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
User.findOne({ id: userId }, function(err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      .....
    });
```

and

```
User.findOne({ id: userId })
.then((result)=>{
   ......
})
.catch((err)=>res.send(err));
```

Comment: One uses a callback, the other promises for what to do when it's finished.

Comment: First method is the tradition way, it includes callback functions and capturing the error through "Error first call back".

Second method uses Promises concept, so the find is successful it will goes to then statement, suppose any error occurred it will goes to catch block.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same question. What I found out :

From a functionnal point of view, if we except the `res.send(err)` which sends the error to the client in the second syntax, both are equivalent and do the same thing : proceed an asynchronous call of Mongoose `Model.FindOne()` function, with an error catch.

From a technical point of view, first syntax uses a [javascript callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function) to do so, the second one, a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).